# JSONP Request to limit rows

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I need to limit my returned rows from a JSON database to 50 rows but after a feverish night of trial and error I still can't work it out? Here's my JSONP request code. I tried the Sparkfun API Docs but they're quite limited and I couldn't work out how to use them in my code. http://phant.io/api/metadata/   Any help would be appreciated?

```
// JSONP request
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
        data: {page: 1},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function (results) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Baro');

        $.each(results, function (i, row) {
            data.addRow([
                (new Date(row.timestamp)),
                 parseFloat(row.Baro)
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to limit the actual response you're getting from sparkfun, or do you just want to stop the loop in the success handler after 50 rows? There's a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to JSONP so I'm not quite sure of the distinction between the two options. I only want to receive the most recent 50 records if that helps?

Comment: That helps, and for that you'd have to read the API documentation to see what they support and what the syntax is, there is no "works everywhere" solution. To just break the loop, just do `if (i >= 50) return false`

Comment: I tried adding your suggested code after "$.each(results, function (i, row) {" line but I still get all rows. It's probably a simple solution but I'm only new at Javascript. I also added the link to the API docs in my edit. There's some interesting info in the Methods under "each" and "limit" but I can't work out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this solution was one of the first things I originally tried but it now seems to work so not sure what has changed exactly but this works if anyone is interested. It's the "data:" line where I added the "{limit: 50}". I would like to have been able to get adeneo's suggestion to work but that's just me being anal.

```
        // JSONP request
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
      data: {limit: 50},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function (results) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the results filtered by time, was useful for me. I liked the Date.js semantics

```js
var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
     // Verbage comes from Data.js
     // day(s), week(s), month(s) and year(s) are supported.
     data: {
         'gte': {
             'timestamp': 'now - 48 hours'
         }
     },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
})
```

Comment: That's a good idea... it's been a while since that project but I'll have another look at it and see if the results are better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sparkfun has added new options to phant, but the documentation is yet to be updated.

A new `limit` option is added that limits the results to last n records.

Details of new options are available at https://github.com/sparkfun/phant/pull/85.